# How do I stop VSCode from automatically adding quotes to JSX element attributes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code

Recently, VSCode has started adding double quotes when auto-completing JSX attribute names. For example, auto-completing `className` will finish the attribute name, add a pair of double quotes, and move the cursor into the quotes:

[image: Example of JSX attribute auto-completion]

I prefer to add the quotes myself so I would like to disable this feature.

Answer (score 7):

VSCode added [JSX Attribute Completions](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_63#_jsx-attribute-completions) in the November, 2021 update. This can be disabled by changing `"javascript.preferences.jsxAttributeCompletionStyle"` and `"typescript.preferences.jsxAttributeCompletionStyle"` to `"none"` in the settings.